# Cell elements as comma separated input arguments for varargin function

Tags: matlab, cell-array, function-call

Imagine a function with a variable number of input arguments, alternately asking for a string and a value.

```
myfunction('string1',value1,'string2',value2,...)
```

e.g.

```
myfunction('A',5,'B',10)
```

I want to keep the ability to call the function like that and I dont want to change the evaluation of `varargin` inside the function. (Except `('string1','string2',...,value1,value2,...)` if that helps)

But I also have my input strings and values stored in a cell array `inputvar <4x1 cell>`:

```
inputvar = 

'A'    [5]    'B'    [10]
```

Also this cell array has a variable length.

My intention is to call my function somehow as follows:

```
myfunction( inputvar )
```

which is obviously not working. Any ideas how I could transform my cell to a valid input syntax?

---

I already tried to generate a string like

```
''string1',value1,'string2',value2'
```

and use `eval` to use it in the function call. But it didn't worked out. So alternatively is there a way to transfor a string to code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
myfunction(inputvar{:})
```

`{:}` creates a [comma separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html?s_tid=doc_12b)

---

**EDIT:**
For example:

```
function val = myfunction(string1,value1,string2,value2)
    if string1 == 'A'
      val = value1;
    else
      val = value2;
end

myfunction('A',5,'B',10)
myfunction('B',5,'B',10)
A = {'A',5,'B',10};
myfunction(A{:})
A = {'B',5,'B',10};
myfunction(A{:})
```

returns:

```
ans =  5
ans =  10
ans =  5
ans =  10
```

Comment: ... which brings me to the problem that I get the char `A` and not the string `'A'`. I'm sure I can find a solution for that myself, but I'd appreciate any fast thoughts ;)

Comment: @thewaywewalk I'm not sure what you mean, it works for the example I just added?

Comment: I lost the overview what my actually mistake was, but it's finally working. thanks!